# 'iptables -S' to be accessed by www-data

Tags: php, iptables

I've had a look around on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) and can't find an answer to what I'm looking for.

Basically, I have an *admin panel* for a website I run and recently just installed `fail2ban`, which has made my average inbox count fly through the roof with new IP bans for failed SSH attempts.

On my admin panel, I have counters for various things and I'd like to include iptable's rules. I can work this out myself, I am just stumped on a certain step.

How could I allow the command: `iptables -S` to be executed by PHP's `shell_exec` command? Or any executable command.

I have tried including access to it by using the sudoers file but no luck.

Comment: I would be ***extremely*** careful giving `www-data` access to execute `iptables` commands - typically you would NOT give anything web-facing access to `iptables` because of the infinite security risks that you could open yourself to with web-facing scripts editing iptables stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the content of your sudoers file?

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/iptables
```

Make sure to pass the full path of the executable.

Here is code in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess as sp
sp.call(['sudo', '/sbin/iptables' , '-S'])
```

Here is someone who encountered a similar problem in PHP:

https://serverfault.com/questions/554019/allow-www-data-to-execute-shell-script

Comment: I did exactly that in the sudoers file, but after running `shell_exec('iptables -S');`, it didn't output anything. I forget if the sudoers file needs to be refreshed to apply the changes. If so, what's that command?

Comment: You need to run: shell_exec('sudo iptables -S');

Comment: That one bit I missed out. Thanks ever so much!